# List.size() null pointer exception

Tags: java, android

I am new to android programming I have seen a tutorial to get the file name from server and store it into list and build a listview to show all files but it is giving me null pointer error. Can anyone please help me to correct my code and try to tell me whats my error so I can learn.Here is the code

```
public class VideoGalleryList extends AppCompatActivity {

    URL url1;
    List serverDir;
    ListView galleryList;
    public final String TAG="data.dot";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_gallery_list);
        findViews();
    }

    protected void findViews() {
        galleryList = findViewById(R.id.gallerylist);
        List arraylist=GetfromServer();
        ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter= new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arraylist);
        galleryList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    }
    public List GetfromServer(){
        try {
            url1=new URL("http://myipaddress/videos/");
            ApacheURLLister lister = new ApacheURLLister();
            serverDir=lister.listAll(url1);
            Log.d(TAG,serverDir.toString());
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return serverDir;

    }

}
```

my error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.a49ersense, PID: 2022
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.a49ersense/com.example.a49ersense.VideoGalleryList}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:392)
        at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:585)
        at com.example.a49ersense.VideoGalleryList.findViews(VideoGalleryList.java:34)
        at com.example.a49ersense.VideoGalleryList.onCreate(VideoGalleryList.java:27)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but this is not I am looking for the link you provide shows how to remove null pointer and it shows if there is null in listview listview wont get initialized. But I dont want that I have files in the directory so there should not be any null value. Thank you for your efforts @VivekMishra

Comment: The `ArrayList` you're passing to the `ArrayAdapter` is null, which means that `GetfromServer()` is returning null. The code in the `try` block there is likely throwing an Exception. Look further up in your logcat for the stack trace you're printing in that `catch`.

Comment: @BhavinThakar, the error is clear that your list is null....

Comment: @BhavinThakar link that I provided, will not provide exact answer to your question. It provides a guideline according to  which you can check your case

Comment: But sir I am having files in the directory so it should not return null @MikeM.

Comment: @BhavinThakar, once debug and check whether the response is  null or something else

Comment: Sir it is not showing anything in logcat so I think so its null@VijayaVarmaLanke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will work for you.

In your `findViews()` method initialize your list

```
serverDir = new ArrayList();
```

And use `GetfromServer()` method like this

```java
public List GetfromServer(){
    try {
        url1=new URL("http://myipaddress/videos/");
        ApacheURLLister lister = new ApacheURLLister();
        serverDir.addAll(lister.listAll(url1));
        Log.d(TAG,serverDir.toString());
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return serverDir;
}
```

Comment: It worked Thank You

Answer (score -2):

First check null pointer exception ,

```
    List arraylist=GetfromServer();
      if(arraylist!= null){
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter= new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arraylist);
    galleryList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter)
      };

 or 

  List arraylist = new ArrayList<>();
  arraylist=GetfromServer();
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter= new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arraylist);
    galleryList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter)
```

Because your function getFromServer function may return null value so you first initialize your variable